# When do we need generics <> notation?

Tags: java, generics

I was reading about the implementation of [MinPQ](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/MinPQ.java.html) and I'm a little confused about when to use the generics notation. Before, I assumed you only do it when relating to a class, such as in the return type, or in the interface like in `Iterable<Key>`. It was right until I met the following usage.

```
public class MinPQ<Key> implements Iterable<Key> { //I understand this
    public MinPQ(int initCapacity) {
        pq = (Key[]) new Object[initCapacity + 1];
        N = 0;
    }  //also clear

    public Iterator<Key> iterator() { return new HeapIterator(); }

    private class HeapIterator implements Iterator<Key> { 
    // Why does HeapIterator not need the generic notation here?

        private MinPQ<Key> copy;
        public HeapIterator() {
            if (comparator == null) 
                copy = new MinPQ<Key>(size());
                //where does this generics come from, no constructor is declared this way
            else                   
                copy = new MinPQ<Key>(size(), comparator);

            for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
                copy.insert(pq[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it

```
private class HeapIterator implements Iterator<Key>
```

instead of

```
private class HeapIterator<Key> implements Iterator<Key>
```

Also, when we call a constructor, is the class declaration the only determinant of whether it uses generics or not?

Comment: `MinPQ` is generic here not `HeapIterator`. `MinPQ<Key>(size())` is constructor of `MinPQ` not `HeapIterator`. you might be confuse with two classes instead of generic.

Comment: `Iterator<Key>` is a concrete type interface parameterized from `Iterator<T>` , so first answer the question that do you need generic for the class `HeapIterator`? In this case I see declaring `private class HeapIterator<Key> implements Iterator<Key>` makes no sense.

Comment: @Arcobaleno, an example:   public class Stack<Item> implements Iterable<Item>   from   http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Stack.java.html

Comment: @javarookie Did you try writing it into an IDE like Eclipse, I would expect you'll get a warning, the type parameter of subclass has nothing to do with the parent's one, so it's ok to do `class HeapIterator<T> implements Iterator<Key>`, but `class HeapIterator<Key> implements Iterator<Key>` would yield a warning as compiler suspects conflict between the type parameter `Key` from class `HeapIterator` with type `Key` parameterized for `Iterator`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with a simpler example. Consider this class declaration:

```
public class IntIterator implements Iterator<Integer>
```

What does this do? It defines a class that implements `Iterator`, but it only works for `Integer` types. This class has predefined the type that it will be using when it implements `next()`, `next()` will have to return an `Integer` because that's the interface it declared by specifying a particular type.

Now what if I want a more general iterator? I might define a class like this:

```
public class GeneralIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
```

This looks somewhat similar, but it's *very* different. Here, I've said, "My `GeneralIterator` is a generic class. You have to tell me what type it works with, and all the `Iterator` methods will use the same type that you tell me to." Here, `GeneralIterator<T>` creates the type parameter, and `Iterator<T>` is *using* that type parameter.

Now let's take a closer look at your example. Let's start with the top class definition:

```
public class MinPQ<Key> implements Iterable<Key>
```

You say you understand this. Good! You understand that this is like my `GeneralIterator<T>` example above. `MinPQ<Key>` *creates* a type parameter named `Key`, and it declares that it implements `Iterable` *using* that type parameter. So now we're left with the confusing part, the inner class declaration:

```
private class HeapIterator implements Iterator<Key>
```

This is more like my first example, but it's a little different, too. Instead of specifying a concrete class, it's *reusing the generic type parameter created by `MinPG<Key>`*. This makes perfect sense. `HeapIterator` doesn't want to create its *own* type parameter; it wants to use the same one as the outer class! And that's exactly what it's doing. All this means is that the implementation of `HeapIterator` uses the same type as its outer `MinPG<Key>`.

If they had written:

```
private class HeapIterator<Key> implements Iterator<Key>
```

that would be very different. It would make `HeapIterator` create a *new* type parameter, that could be different than the one defined by `MinPG<Key>`.

Armed with this understanding, the instantiation of a new `MinPG<Key>` in `HeapIterator`'s constructor is a little easier. This is again *using* the type parameter defined by `MinPG<Key>`. It's just saying, "This instance of `MinPG` has to use the same type as the original one," instead of allowing for different types inside the `HeapIterator` class.

**TL;DR:** This is all about making sure the types of all the objects match up and don't allow for weird things where the types are different.

Comment: your answer is conflicting following answer in the first case, he suggests it should be HeapIterator<Key> i = new HeapIterator();

Comment: @javarookie That doesn't make any sense. Why in the world would the variable have a type declaration and the constructor call not have one? I'm reworking my answer.

Comment: @javarookie I've reworked the answer. Hopefully, this is more thorough and helps your understand more.

Comment: @javarookie I'm glad to help. If one of the answers here is sufficient for your question, please consider accepting it (by clicking the check mark below the up/down voting buttons). (It doesn't have to be mine if you think another one is better, of course. Just please get in the habit of accepting an answer when one sufficiently answers your question, or posting/accepting your own if you figure it out yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

It is just another way to write generic , some time it makes code little simple you don't have to think about what type is.

```
private class HeapIterator <Type> implements Iterator <Type>
```

Using above approach means that this class has type parameter and when instance is constructed then it must be specified.

for e.g to create instance you have to use below statement

```
HeapIterator <Key> itr = new HeapIterator<Key>();
```

---

```
private class HeapIterator implements Iterator<Key>
```

There is no type parameter to this class and "Key" is valid type and this class is binded with this type at compile time only.

for e.g to create instance you have to use below statement

```
HeapIterator ir = new HeapIterator();
```

Comment: for your 2nd example, do you need HeapIterator<Key> ir or just HeapIterator ir ?  Is this what you mean by binding at compile time by creating an instance this way HeapIterator<Key> ir?

Comment: yours conflicting the previous answer, mind taking a look, it suggests what I assumed HeapIterator ir = new HeapIterator in your second example

Comment: you are correct, i made typo there. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there are two things going on here.  One is that Java has support for raw types...

```
Raw Types
To facilitate interfacing with non-generic legacy code, it is possible to use as a type
the erasure (§4.6) of a parameterized type (§4.5) or the erasure of an array type
(§10.1) whose element type is a parameterized type. Such a type is called a raw
type.
More precisely, a raw type is defined to be one of:
• The reference type that is formed by taking the name of a generic type declaration
without an accompanying type argument list.
• An array type whose element type is a raw type.
• A non-static member type of a raw type R that is not inherited from a superclass
or superinterface of R.
A non-generic class or interface type is not a raw type.
To see why a non-static type member of a raw type is considered raw, consider the
following example:
class Outer<T>{
 T t;
 class Inner {
 T setOuterT(T t1) { t = t1; return t; }
 }
}
The type of the member(s) of Inner depends on the type parameter of Outer. If Outer is
raw, Inner must be treated as raw as well, as there is no valid binding for T.
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf
THis may explain your question 1.

Question 2 may be explained by bridge method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html

```
Bridge Methods

When compiling a class or interface that extends a parameterized class or implements a parameterized interface, the compiler may need to create a synthetic method, called a bridge method, as part of the type erasure process. You normally don't need to worry about bridge methods, but you might be puzzled if one appears in a stack trace.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is fairly simple:

1. In example 1, your class is not generic and the generic parameter *type* it implements is `Key`
2. In example 2, your class is generic its generic parameter *name* is `Key'

Assuming you have a class named `Key`, the generic parameter name `Key` in *hiding* or *shadowing* the class name `Key`; the second example's code is identical to:

```
private class HeapIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
```